# Unattended-Upgrade Fail

Tags: apt

I have unattended upgrades enabled however for some reason the following packages were not updated:

msodbcsql:amd64 (13.1.9.2-1, 17.0.1.1-1), 
mssql-tools:amd64 (14.0.6.0-1, 17.0.1.1-1)

I have the following config set in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades:

```
    // Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
        // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
        // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
        // should also install from here by default.
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

less /var/log/apt/history.log (dist-upgrade done manually at the end):

```
  Start-Date: 2018-02-01  06:57:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-4.4.0-1050-aws:amd64 (4.4.0-1050.59, automatic), linux-tools-4.4.0-1050-aws:amd64 (4.4.0-1050.59, automatic), linux-aws-tools-4.4.0-1050:amd64 (4.4.0-1050.59, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-1050-aws:amd64 (4.4.0-1050.59, automatic), linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1050:amd64 (4.4.0-1050.59, automatic)
Upgrade: libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.5, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6), linux-headers-aws:amd64 (4.4.0.1049.51, 4.4.0.1050.52), linux-aws:amd64 (4.4.0.1049.51, 4.4.0.1050.52), linux-image-aws:amd64 (4.4.0.1049.51, 4.4.0.1050.52), linux-tools-aws:amd64 (4.4.0.1049.51, 4.4.0.1050.52), curl:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.5, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.5, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6)
End-Date: 2018-02-01  06:57:20

Start-Date: 2018-02-06  06:43:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), grub-pc:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), systemd-sysv:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1)
End-Date: 2018-02-06  06:43:18

Start-Date: 2018-02-10  06:58:08
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libparted2:amd64 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), libapparmor-perl:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), parted:amd64 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), sosreport:amd64 (3.4-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 3.5-1~ubuntu16.04.2), apparmor:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), cloud-guest-utils:amd64 (0.27-0ubuntu24, 0.27-0ubuntu25)
End-Date: 2018-02-10  06:58:12

Start-Date: 2018-02-12  13:11:28
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Upgrade: msodbcsql:amd64 (13.1.9.2-1, 17.0.1.1-1), mssql-tools:amd64 (14.0.6.0-1, 17.0.1.1-1)
End-Date: 2018-02-12  13:11:32
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated..

Cheers

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages `msodbcsql` and `mssql-tools` are not in the Ubuntu repositories - you get them from someplace else.

Since that 'someplace else' repository is not listed in your Allowed-Origins, those packages won't be upgraded automatically.

Here is a [very good example](https://linux-audit.com/upgrading-external-packages-with-unattended-upgrade/) of how to add non-Ubuntu sources to Allowed-Origins.

**Safety Warning for future readers**: It's generally unwise to enable automatic upgrade from *all* sources. A bad upgrade may break your system. Good upgrades from different sources may unintentionally introduce a file conflict, version conflict, or other pernicious problem. Ubuntu's default setting is only to enable security upgrades from  Ubuntu's own security repo for precisely this reason.